# Why my /tmp on Debian 9 have 15GB

Tags: debian, debian-stretch, tmpfs

My Debian 9 `/tmp` folder have 15GB (44 days uptime).
Am I supposted to manually (or with cronjob) delete /tmp contents?

OR something is wrong :D

Comment: What _are_ its contents right now?

Comment: Usually cron removes older files automatically. You could run a "du" command in the folder to see where the space is being taken.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with asking here, but you may find an answer more quickly in the future by using http://unix.stackexchange.com . You can search there for an answer to this issue, but please don't double-post on both sites.

Comment: @user1686 seems like uploaded files from POST forms are most of the content (upload_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)